# What is the most efficient circle-circle collision algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on a sweep-line that will detect circle-circle collisions as fast as possible, I am just wondering if anyone knows of a **more efficient** way than sweep-line. My code is more a hybrid of line-line, using the maximum potential circle size to remove active circles when they cannot possibly be colliding.

If anyone knows a better or can give me feedback on how much more efficient I have actually made the task I would be very grateful, this one hurts my brain just thinking about it.

**Javascript**

```js
var Width = 1200
var Height = 1200
const svg = document.getElementById('svg1')
svg.setAttribute('width', Width)
svg.setAttribute('height', Height)

function seg(x, y, c) {
  var segment = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle")
  segment.setAttribute("cx", x)
  segment.setAttribute("cy", y)
  segment.setAttribute("r", c)
  svg.appendChild(segment)
}

function seg2(x, y, c) {
  var segment = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle")
  segment.setAttribute("cx", x)
  segment.setAttribute("cy", y)
  segment.setAttribute("r", c)
  segment.setAttribute('fill', '#0f0')
  svg.appendChild(segment)
}

function seg3(x, y, c) {
  var segment = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle")
  segment.setAttribute("cx", x)
  segment.setAttribute("cy", y)
  segment.setAttribute("r", c)
  segment.setAttribute('fill', '#ff0')
  svg.appendChild(segment)
}
const circles = []
var addPoints = function(n) {
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var o = {
      x: Math.random() * 1000,
      y: Math.random() * 1000,
      c: (Math.random() * 5) + 5
    }
    circles.push(o)
    seg(o.x, o.y, o.c)
  }
}
addPoints(1000)

circles.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.x > b.x) return 1
  if (a.x < b.x) return -1
  return 0
})

var peak = function(a) {
  L = 0
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].c > L) {
      L = a[i].c
    }
  }
  return L
}

var sweep = function(J) {
  var A = []
  var M = peak(J)
  for (i = 0; i < J.length; i++) {

    if (A.length > 0) {
      for (k = 0; k < A.length; k++) {
        ea = A[k].x + A[k].c
        jm = J[i].x - M
        if (ea < jm) {
          A.splice(k, 1)
        } else {
          bj = J[i].x - J[i].c
          if ((bj - ea) < 0) {
            yy = Math.abs(A[k].y - J[i].y)
            yt = A[k].c + J[i].c
            if (yy < yt) {
              xx = J[i].x - A[k].x
              yy = J[i].y - A[k].y
              cc = Math.sqrt((xx * xx) + (yy * yy))
              dd = J[i].c + A[k].c
              if (cc < dd) {
                seg2(A[k].x, A[k].y, A[k].c)
                seg3(J[i].x, J[i].y, J[i].c)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    A.push(J[i])
  }
}
sweep(circles)
```

```html
<svg id="svg1"></svg>
```

Comment: Separating Axis Theorem is what I always liked, don't know if it is the most efficient one out there

Comment: I had a look at the theory behind this (separating axis), is there a way of doing that with thousands of points in an algorithm? I just see tutorials on object-object, and I guessed you only needed to find the hypotenuse for circle-circle and compare with combined circumference.

Comment: By points if you meant circles, for anything above 50 circles, its best to use a Quadtree of 10 circles.

Answer (score 1):

The separate axis theorem is the easy way here. For circles, it's even easier; you just need to check the radius and the distance between the circles. Here's one approach that runs in `O(n log n)` time on average:

1. Create a quadtree of any depth you like (static or dynamic; deep enough but not too deep)
2. Foreach circle in your map, insert it into the quadtree.
3. Foreach circle in your map, look at all positions in the quadtree at most `2r` from your circle's center. If there's nothing there, and no other circle finds us, this circle does not collide with anything.